# Empty all variables in javascript function each run

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript validation function that looks like the following -

**Trigger**

```
add_action ('wp_head', 'trigger_validatior');
function trigger_validatior() {
    echo'
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("#gform_submit_button_5").click(function() {
                return Form_5_Contact_Validator(gform_5);
            });
        }); 
        </script> 
    ';
}
```

**Function  (simplified)**

The validation that I am demonstrating is supposed to run if (1) the field is not empty AND (2) the field value is less than `2`. (I do not want the function to run if the field is left blank.)

```
function Form_5_Contact_Validator(Form){

var valOne = Form.input_1.value;        // get form data    
if (valOne < '2' && valOne != ''){      // validation check, if fails - then...
    alert("Error: Alert Error.");       // alert the user               
    return (false);                                                                         
}                                       // endif

var valTwo = Form.input_2.value;        
if (valTwo < '1' && valTwo != ''){     
    alert("Error: Alert Error.");               
    return (false);                                                                         
}                                    

}                                       // end validation
```

If I enter data into the form that is not correct - IE, I enter `1` for `valOne`, my alerts pop up.

When I correct the value in `valOne` to be 2 or greater no alert pops up **but my form fails to submit**. Why is `return (false);` staying active even after I correct the value?

**Solutions**

I tried adding `return(true);` at the beginning of the function which simply returned true before doing the validations.

I tried adding `return(true_;` at the end of the function, but still, the function wouldn't complete even when the values were correct.

I tried modifying the validation statements like so:

```
var valTwo = Form.input_2.value;        
if (valTwo < '1' && valTwo != ''){     
    alert("Error: Alert Error.");               
    return (false);                                                                         
} else {
    return (true);
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: How are you calling this function? e.g. `<form onsubmit="return Form_5_Contact_Validator(this)">`

Comment: if (valOne < '2' && valOne != '') this looks wrong should it be if (valOne < '2' || valOne != '')

Comment: I didn't understand the question but assuming `Form_5_Contact_Validator` runs upon every `submit` event, `attempt` will always be initialized with `2` since it's local.

Comment: By the way I can see that you do have a problem with `errorList` being reset to an empty array on each run, so when attempt reaches 0, nothing will sent to the error page. You need to declare `errorList` outside the function to keep hold of the errors for all previous attempts.

Comment: Do you actually ever `return true;`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Amit - I hope my edit is an improvement.

Comment: @Rhumborl - I've included the trigger and in my original function, the arrays were outside the function. I made an error while transposing. I eliminated the extra stuff to clarify the question.

Comment: @Icepickle - I've added some methods I tried in order to `return(true);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option One**

To simply proceed with the javascript validations that you currently have, you can alter your jQuery trigger. I believe that in your current trigger, the return value is actually returning to the .ready() function, and is therefore "absorbed", if you will.

Additionally, be sure that you stop jQuery from performing the default operation when a function ends with `return false`, as the default behavior is to allow subsequent functions to continue to run.

Please try modifying your trigger like so:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#gform_submit_button_5").click(function(event) {
        if (Form_5_Contact_Validator(gform_5)) {
            $(gform_5).submit();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();                
    });
});
</script>
```

**Option Two**

Your current solution isn't in compliance with some best-practice standards. Consider these options:

You maybe able to achieve what you are looking to do, by installing and using the [Jquery Validation For Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-validation-for-contact-form-7/) plugin.

I tend to discourage the injection of random `<script>` blocks into the `<head>`. In my humble opinion, it is bad practice.

If the suggested wordpress plugin does not meet your needs, and since I see jQuery involved here, let me recommend the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Register and enqueue for wordpress usage by adding the following to an appropriate `functions.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * form_add_scripts - callback for registering the form's required javascript files
 *
 * @return void
 */
function form_add_scripts() {
    $base   = array("jquery");
    $custom = array("jquery", "jquery-validate-script", "jquery-validate-script-additional");
    wp_register_script("jquery-validate-script", "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js", $base);
    wp_enqueue_script("jquery-validate-script");
    wp_register_script("jquery-validate-script-additional", "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js", $base);
    wp_enqueue_script("jquery-validate-script-additional");
    wp_register_script("form-script", get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/form.js", $custom);
    wp_enqueue_script("form-script");
}
// inform wordpress of the additional scripts
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", form_add_scripts);
```

`functions.php` is found either with the `wp-content/themes/name-of-theme` directory (of the theme your are currently using) or if you're like me, and prefer updates to happen with little to no hand-holding, create a child theme (You can find this on the wordpress codex. would have posted a link, but I don't have enough rep).

The last register/enqueue file listed, `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/form.js"`, is meant to go into the same directory as the `functions.php` file, that you would have added the previous code block to. This is where you would place any custom triggers, if you even need them, and also the definition of what type of validation should take place.

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/form.js"`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/
    $('#form-id-name').validate({
        rules: {
            'input-one-id-name': {
                digits: true,
                min: 2
            },
            'input-two-id-name': {
                digits: true,
                min: 2
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Error messages can be styled and verbiage customized as needed. Please refer to the validation plugin documentation.